# Is the magnetic field calculated from $B=\frac{μ_{0}nI}{2}(\sin α+\sinβ)$ the magnetic field at a point on the axis of a solenoid only?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is the magnetic field calculated from $B=\frac{μ_{0}nI}{2}(\sin α+\sinβ)$ the magnetic field at a point on the axis of a circular solenoid only or at any point on the circular cross section whose center point is the point on the axis?

Answer (score 0):

That formula gives B only on the axis of solenoid. This should be seen in the derivation of the formula in the textbook where you found the equation.